# UIScrollView loses contentheight

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIScrollView where i dynamically fill with labels. This happens in a 'setDetails' method.

I also have a button, wich triggers a segue. With use of the UINavigationController, i can go back to the first view with the 'back' button. When I go back, i can't scroll the UIScrollView to the end anymore. It somehow loses his contentheight. Weird is: When I do the setDetails again, (same content) it doesnt solve the problem. If I do a setDetails with other data, the problem solves...

Anyone who knows what i can do? Ive tried almost everything. Google didn't help me a lot :)

thanks

this is the method who will fill the scrollview.(_detailScroll). This is a scrollview that I added on the Storyboard. It calculates the contentsize of the scrollview.

this method is called by a 'sub'viewcontroller.

```
-(void)setDetails:(GFilm*) gFilm



{

//REMOVING LABELS
[titleCast removeFromSuperview];
titleCast = nil;
[titlePlot removeFromSuperview];
titlePlot = nil;
[titleRegie removeFromSuperview];
titleRegie = nil;
[regie removeFromSuperview];
regie = nil;
[cast removeFromSuperview];
cast = nil;
[plot removeFromSuperview];
plot = nil;

//SCROLL TO TOP
[_detailScroll scrollToTop];

//MAKING LABELS
CGFloat upX = 15;
CGFloat upY = 0;


CGRect rectTitleRegie = CGRectMake(upX, upY, 100, 16);
titleRegie = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rectTitleRegie];
titleRegie.numberOfLines = 1;
titleRegie.font = [titleRegie.font fontWithSize:12];
titleRegie.text = @"Regie:";
titleRegie.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:160/255.0f blue:8/255.0f alpha:1];



CGRect rectRegie = titleRegie.frame;
rectRegie.origin.x += 40;
rectRegie.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - _detailScroll.frame.origin.x - rectRegie.origin.x - upX;
regie = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectRegie];
regie.font = [regie.font fontWithSize:12];
regie.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSMutableString* reg = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < gFilm.directorList.count; i++)
{
    Director* d = [gFilm.directorList objectAtIndex:i];
    [reg appendString: d.name];
}
if(gFilm.directorList.count == 0)
{
    regie.text = @"N/A";
}
else
{
    regie.text = reg;
}



upY = regie.frame.origin.y + regie.frame.size.height + 7;

CGRect rectTitleCast = CGRectMake(upX,upY, 100, 16);
titleCast = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectTitleCast];
titleCast.text = @"Cast:";
titleCast.numberOfLines = 1;
titleCast.font = [titleCast.font fontWithSize:12];
titleCast.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:160/255.0f blue:8/255.0f alpha:1];



CGRect rectCast = titleCast.frame;
rectCast.origin.x += 40;
rectCast.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - _detailScroll.frame.origin.x - rectCast.origin.x - upX;;
cast = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rectCast];
cast.numberOfLines = 0;
cast.font = [cast.font fontWithSize:12];
cast.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

NSMutableString* castStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
for(int i = 0; i < gFilm.castList.count; i++)
{
    Cast* c = [gFilm.castList objectAtIndex:i];
    [castStr appendString: c.name];
    if([c.role length] != 0)
        {
            [castStr appendString: @"  :  "];
            [castStr appendString: c.role];
        }
    if(i != gFilm.castList.count - 1)
    {
        //_lblCast.numberOfLines +=1;
        [castStr appendString:@"\n"];
    }
}
if(gFilm.castList.count == 0)
{
    cast.text = @"N/A";
}
else
{
    cast.text = castStr;
}

//Customize height of label to fit content...
CGSize size = [cast.text sizeWithFont:cast.font
                    constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cast.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGRect labelFrame = cast.frame;
labelFrame.size.height = size.height;
cast.frame = labelFrame;


upY = cast.frame.origin.y + cast.frame.size.height + 7;

CGRect rectTitlePlot = CGRectMake(upX, upY, 100, 16);
titlePlot = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rectTitlePlot];
titlePlot.numberOfLines = 1;
titlePlot.font = [titlePlot.font fontWithSize:12];
titlePlot.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:160/255.0f blue:8/255.0f alpha:1];
titlePlot.text = @"Plot:";


CGRect rectPlot = titlePlot.frame;
rectPlot.origin.x += 40;
rectPlot.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - _detailScroll.frame.origin.x - rectPlot.origin.x - upX;
plot = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rectPlot];
plot.font = [plot.font fontWithSize:12];
plot.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
plot.numberOfLines = 0;
plot.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
if([gFilm.plot length] == 0)
{
    plot.text = @"N/A";
}
else
{
    plot.text = gFilm.plot;
}

CGSize plotsize = [plot.text sizeWithFont:plot.font
                        constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(plot.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGRect plotlabelFrame = plot.frame;
plotlabelFrame.size.height = plotsize.height;
plot.frame = plotlabelFrame;



CGSize checkWidth =[gFilm.filmTitle sizeWithFont:_lblTitel.font];
if(checkWidth.width > _lblTitel.frame.size.width)
{
    CGFloat temp = titleFontSize - 4.0;
    _lblTitel.font = [_lblTitel.font fontWithSize:temp];

}
else
{
    _lblTitel.font = [_lblTitel.font fontWithSize:titleFontSize];
}

_lblTitel.text = gFilm.filmTitle;
NSMutableString* datNP = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
GTimePerformance* nextPerf = gFilm.firstPerformance;

if([nextPerf.date length] != 0 && [nextPerf.performanceTime length] != 0)
{
    [datNP appendString: nextPerf.date];
    [datNP appendString:@" - "];
    [datNP appendString:nextPerf.performanceTime];
}
else
{
    datNP = @"N/A";
}

 nextPerformance.text = datNP;



CGFloat contentWidth = self.view.frame.size.width -  (2*upX);
CGFloat contentHeight = upY + plot.frame.size.height + 7;
contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight);

[_detailScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(contentWidth, contentHeight)];
[_detailScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

//Adding labels to scrollview..
[_detailScroll addSubview:titleRegie];
[_detailScroll addSubview:regie];
[_detailScroll addSubview:titleCast];
[_detailScroll addSubview:cast];
[_detailScroll addSubview:titlePlot];
[_detailScroll addSubview:plot];


}
```

No problem until then:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segueName isEqualToString: @"showDetail"])
    {
        DetailViewController* dvc = (DetailViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        [dvc setMovie:[_coverFlowViewController getCurrentMovie]];
    }
}
```

When i push to this view, and go back, the scrollview doesn't scroll to the full bottom.

Comment: You'll need to post some code before people can help properly

Comment: Added some details on the code..